# Making a the element of a list inside a list not aliases

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Basically given a list:

```
a = [2]
```

I want to make the output to be:

```
b = [[2,2],[2,2]]
```

Then changing one of the element in list of list without affecting the other list of list:

```
b[0][1] = 1
```

so the new output for b should be:

```
b = [[2,1],[2,2]]
```

But when I tried, making duplicate to prevent aliases, the result still comes down to `b = [[2,1],[2,1]]` and through the visualizer, `b[0]` and `b[1]` pointed to the same address of inner list.

This is how I tried to approach the problem in the visualizer
    a = [2]

```
b = a + a 

c = [b[:]]

c1 = c[:]

d = c + c1

d[0][1] = 1    

print(d)
```

the print function printed:

```
[[2,1],[2,1]]
```

Looking at the steps in the visualizer, the list in d pointed to the same list of list in c. Can't figure out how to make them not pointing to the same place.

Comment: welcome to SO. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Show your code of building `b` from `a`.

Comment: We'll going to need the exact code to understand how you're failing here.

Answer (score 1):

In python, if you do `b=[a,a]*2`, you're gonna have two references to the same list. You have to append a copy of the first element of you want two separate lists.

```
b = [a,a]
b == [[a,a],[a,a]] #Two references to the same list
b[0][1] = c
b == [[a,c],[a,c]]

b = [[a,a]]
b.append(b[0][:]) #Appends copy of first list
b ==[[a,a],[a,a]] #Two separate, identical lists
b[0][1] = c
b == [[a,c],[a,a]]
```

The `[:]` is important so that you append the elements of the first list, instead of a reference to the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `deepcopy` to copy objects nested in your object properly

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = [2]
b = a + a
c = [b, deepcopy(b)]
```

Comment: I haven't learn deepcopy yet and does not know what it really does. The answer works perfectly but is there any other way around the problem without using deepcopy?

Comment: for performance reasons python doesn't actually copies object containing references unless it is told to do so because if the object is big copying can take time

Answer (score 1):

Start with your code:

```
a  = [2]
b  = a + a
c  = [b[:]]    # [ [2,2] ]
c1 = c[:]      # [ [2,2] ]
```

At this point, `c` and `c1` are different lists (you can confirm that
with the `id()` function). **However**, their respective first elements
are the same list.

```
id(c[0]) == id(c1[0])    # True
```

There are various ways to create fully independent lists in the data
structure. Here are four of them.

```
c1_alt = [list(inner_list) for inner_list in c]

c1_alt = [inner_list[:] for inner_list in c]

c1_alt = map(list, c)

from copy import deepcopy
c1_alt = deepcopy(c)
```